# HTML, Javascript: Read out Cell Input, set as Selection

Tags: javascript, html-table, cell, return-value

I read out the Table-Cell-Input in JS, as follow:

```
...    
var cell_input = table.rows[y].cells[x].innerText;
...
```

**The Problem:** When I read out a Cell, set as a Selection (with different options), I get the Values of all options by ".innerText", instead of only the selected value ("Status").

```
<td>
  <select name="Role" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="status" selected><?php $active ?></option>      //.inner Text = 0 or 1
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

How isit possible to only read out the - Selected / Default - Value "Status"?

Thanks alot for helping me

Answer (score 1):

InnerText does  do this. It's not particularly useful.

Try this:

```
const select = table.rows[y].cells[x].querySelector('select');
const value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var oRole = document.getElementById("Role");
var cell_input = oRole.options[oRole.selectedIndex].text;
```